Github Actions not triggering workflow when a pull request is opened to main (but does work when opening PRs to develop)
All, I have an electron app with a workflow with the following triggers:
name: Build & Scan
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
            - develop
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - main
            - develop
        types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

As you can see, we have a main, develop and then features\ branches. This workflow has been working fantastic from merging features\ into develop.  Everything works as expected (runs on PR open, and when merged).  However, this is our first merge from develop to main. I opened the Pull Request and the PR part of the workflow did not run.  main currently does not have a build.yml file; as I said, this is the first release to main (1.0.0).
As a sanity check, I made a new branch off of main called hotfixes\build-file-only and ONLY checked in the build file from develop. I then opened a PR from this hotfix to main, and lo and behold the PR workflow is triggered and all the checks run.  Again, the build.yml in develop and hotfixes\build-file-only are identical, so why would one PR trigger the workflow and the other wont?  The only thing I can think of is the develop PR is very large as its the first release.
